# Dealing with multiple root paths and scopes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

We have the following routes setup:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "/:locale" do    
    ...other routes
    root :to => 'home#index'
  end
  root :to => 'application#detect_language'
end
```

Which gives us this:

```
root      /:locale(.:format)    home#index
root      /                     application#detect_language
```

which is fine.

However, when we want to generate a route with the locale we hitting trouble:

`root_path` generates `/` which is correct.

`root_path(:locale => :en)` generates `/?locale=en` which is undesirable - we want `/en`

So, question is, is this possible and how so?

Comment: Don't know if question is possible but you can use something like `:as => :home_root` to differentiate them as a workaround.

Answer (score 10):

root method is used by default to define the top level / route.
So, you are defining the same route twice, causing the second definition to override the first!

Here is the definition of root method:

```
def root(options = {})
  options = { :to => options } if options.is_a?(String)
  match '/', { :as => :root, :via => :get }.merge(options)
end
```

It is clear that it uses :root as the named route.
If you want to use the root method just override the needed params.
E.g.

```
scope "/:locale" do    
  ...other routes
  root :to => 'home#index', :as => :root_with_locale
end
root :to => 'application#detect_language'
```

and call this as:

```
root_with_locale_path(:locale => :en)
```

So, this is not a bug!