# Root inside namespace or scope not working with rails 5.0.0-beta1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, ruby-on-rails-5

The following should work as per http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope module: 'admin'  do
    constraints subdomain: 'admin' do
      root to: 'tenants#index'
      resources :tenants
    end
  end
  root to: 'users#index'
  resources :users
end
```

Unfortunately, whichever root is listed first ends up taking over.  As listed, admin.xyz.com will fire tenants#index.  If the outer root to: 'users#index' is moved first in the source order then it becomes the root path for all including admin.xyz.com.

Do I read guide correctly?  I so, this may be a bug in rails 5.0.0-beta1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is you have to put an :as => something_not_root on one or the other that you use in order to use both at the same time. I referenced this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882494/dealing-with-multiple-root-paths-and-scopes-in-rails) for that information

So try this instead

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope module: 'admin'  do
    constraints subdomain: 'admin' do
      root to: 'tenants#index', as: tenants_root
      resources :tenants
    end
  end
  root to: 'users#index'
  resources :users
end
```

and then call it

```
tenants_root_path
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to create a root path inside a namespace (mentioned in the title but not really described in the question), you can do it like this:

```
namespace(:plan) do
  root controller: :plan, action: :index, as: :root
end
```

This will create a plan_root_path helper method. I found this a bit confusing at first because I didn't understand that my use of the namespace would cause rails to automatically prepend the path with the namespace, so I tried code like this:

```
root controller: :plan, action: :index, as: :plan_root
```

which resulted in a plan_plan_root_path helper method being created, which isn't what you want.

I am adding this answer to this question because this question came up as a top response when searching for "rails 5 namespace root path" but the namespace issue isn't solved.